# Kafka: How to list all the topics that have data flowing in them

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I list all the topics that have data flowing in them?

I have a Kafka cluster (Confluent 7.2.1) with zookeeper. And I have over 120 topics where some of them are not active. I can list all the topics using `kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server...`. This will return the list of all the topics.
I am looking to list the topics that currently have data in it. I have data on my topics for up to 7 days.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, there is no easy way to do this.

You would need to loop over every topic, then pass name to [GetOffsetShell](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-tools-GetOffsetShell.html) command with `-1` and `-2` flags to get start and end offsets, then compare them; when they match, the topic is **currently** empty, but that doesn't mean that a new producer didn't spin up within the few seconds you run the tool.

Alternatively, there may be metrics tools like Prometheus exporters that can query the disk-usage of the broker log directories and report empty folders